# C# listing directory via FTP receives dots only

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I try to list all the files in one folder via FTP:

```
 FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
 //uri string - webhost.com/public_html/some_dir/myfolder
 reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + remoteDir + "/" + folder));
 reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
 reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
 reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
 reqFTP.Proxy = null;
 reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
 reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
 reqFTP.Timeout = 300000;//wait for 5 min

 response = reqFTP.GetResponse();

 reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
 string line = reader.ReadLine();

  while (line != null) //line is always '.' here
  {
      if(line.Length > 3)
      {
          line = line.Split('/')[1];
          result.Append(line);
          result.Append("\n");
          line = reader.ReadLine();
      }

  }
```

The connection seems ok, my `response` gets:

```
StatusDescription 150 Connecting to port 50058\r\n
WelcomeMessage 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /\r\n
```

But the problem is that when i read the `line` it is always a single dot. So the while loop goes infinite.

I tried to connect to another server and it's working fine.
I'd appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first entry in a directory is usually a `.` = reference to "this" directory.

And you never get passed that as you read the next entry only within the `if` block, where you never get to.

The code should be like:

```
while (line != null)
{
    if (line.Length > 3)
    {
        line = line.Split('/')[1];
        result.Append(line);
        result.Append("\n");
    }

    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

---

*Though the `line.Length > 3` condition seems suspicious on its own. But that's a different question.*